# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session error using GeckoDriver and Firefox through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I'm trying to run tests on firefox using the below code but running into exception when I run the tests on **Windows Server 2012 R2**. But the same code works on **MAC** and **windows 10**

Firefox version - 72.0.2

Gecko driver version - 0.26

Selenium standalone server for hub and node - 3.141.59

Code for Desired Capabilities:

```
dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
dc.setCapability("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\AutomationPrograms\\geckodriver.exe");
dc.setBrowserName(browser);
dc.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
dc.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
```

Error:

```
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "server:CONFIG_UUID": "b2cccab6-d8e1-4cdb-aac1-10e33ef6a8bd",
    "marionette": true,
    "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
    "loggingPrefs": {
      "browser": "ALL"
    },
    "browserName": "firefox",
    "webdriver.gecko.driver": "C:\\AutomationPrograms\\geckodriver.exe",
    "javascriptEnabled": true,
    "version": ""
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "server:CONFIG_UUID": "b2cccab6-d8e1-4cdb-aac1-10e33ef6a8bd"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'M-AMS-DEVELOPER', ip: '108.61.189.113', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 104.36 seconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at framework.maincontroller.MainController.createDriver(MainController.java:856)
    at framework.maincontroller.MainController.setUp(MainController.java:1197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:599)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "server:CONFIG_UUID": "b2cccab6-d8e1-4cdb-aac1-10e33ef6a8bd",
    "marionette": true,
    "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
    "loggingPrefs": {
      "browser": "ALL"
    },
    "browserName": "firefox",
    "webdriver.gecko.driver": "C:\\AutomationPrograms\\geckodriver.exe",
    "javascriptEnabled": true,
    "version": ""
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "server:CONFIG_UUID": "b2cccab6-d8e1-4cdb-aac1-10e33ef6a8bd"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'M-AMS-DEVELOPER', ip: '108.61.189.113', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'M-AMS-DEVELOPER', ip: '108.61.189.113', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$null$4(NewSessionPipeline.java:76)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$createNewSession$5(NewSessionPipeline.java:75)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.createNewSession(NewSessionPipeline.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession.execute(BeginSession.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0(WebDriverServlet.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run geckdirver.exe file and got error that `vcruntime140.dll was not found`. So I had to download `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 RC` from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685).

And there was a problem with the location of geckodriver.exe as well.

I had placed it in Jenkins workspace and it was not executing. I moved it to a folder other that Jenkins workspace and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'M-AMS-DEVELOPER', ip: '108.61.189.113', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *GeckoDriver*, *Firefox* and *Selenium Client* versions are the latest one.
- But your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_152** which is pretty old.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.

Comment: ty for the solution @DebanjanB. Will try this and get back to you

Comment: @Rameshwar The most recent of JDK 8, the better.

Comment: I tried with jdk 8u241 which is better that 8u222. But still getting same error

Comment: @Rameshwar No you aren't getting the same error. In this question your error was `Driver info: driver.version: unknown` _at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)_, but the error in your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59991805/unable-to-create-session-error-using-geckodriver-and-firefox-through-selenium-an) is `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46285` _at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)_

Comment: Exactly. That's why I created a different question.